# VB get data from excel - validation

Tags: vb.net, excel, validation, get

I have a code which is mainly working except I have a validation error...
My code has a search box where I put the surname in, the idea is that if the surname entered is in the excel sheet and a bunch of information is returned. This works as desired, as does my validation for no data entered in the search box.

What doesn't work is my validation for when I enter something in the search box which isn't a match (i.e. not in the excel sheet). Please see 'match validation' in the following code to see what I'm referring to do.

I just have no idea why it isn't working. I don't even get an error when I run the code and enter in wrong data, it just doesn't return an error message like it should and the form sort of freezes up (kinda like its in a non stop loop).

Any advice would be great, Thanks! Here some of the code:

```
    'define objects
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object


    'Open a existing workbook and sheet in excel
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="c:\users\timothy\desktop\coding\output.xlsx")
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim getSurname As String = ""
    Dim getFirstname As String = ""
    Dim getAge As String = ""
    Dim getGender As String = ""
    Dim getNum As Integer = 1
    Dim getValidate As Integer = 0    

While oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & getNum).value <> searchInput.Text.ToUpper
        getNum = getNum + 1
    End While

'Length Validation (THIS WORKS)
If Len(searchInput.Text) = 0 Then
    getValidate = getValidate + 1
End If

 'Match validation (THIS DOES NOT WORK)
 If oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & getNum).value <> searchInput.Text.ToUpper Then
     getValidate = getValidate + 1
 End If

If getValidate = 0 Then
    getSurname = oSheet.Range("A" & getNum).Value.ToString
    getFirstname = oSheet.Range("B" & getNum).Value.ToString
    getAge = oSheet.Range("C" & getNum).Value.ToString
    getGender = oSheet.Range("D" & getNum).Value.ToString
    outputData.Text = "SURNAME: " & getSurname & vbCrLf & "FIRSTNAME: " & getFirstname & vbCrLf & "AGE: " & getAge & vbCrLf & "GENDER: " & getGender & vbCrLf
Else
    MsgBox("ERROR!! Please enter valid Quote Number.")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section of code

```
While oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & getNum).value <> searchInput.Text.ToUpper
        getNum = getNum + 1
    End While
```

will continue to loop through the worksheet until it finds a match.  Let's assume you get to the last row of your data with no match yet.  The next "A" & getNum will be blank, which will not be a match, and so it will continue the While, until it hits your row limit and errors out.  It never finds a match, so it will never hit your check.

However, I think if you put a check in there to look for those blank cells...

```
 While oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & getNum).value <> searchInput.Text.ToUpper
        if oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & getNum).value  = "" then
            exit while
        else
            getNum = getNum + 1
        end if
    End While
```

,then I think it will do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are going to work on really big spread sheets, you are going to run into trouble looping.   Can you not rather use Find?

See: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?634644-Excel-Find-Method-in-Excel-VBA-(Any-version-of-Excel)

See Down bottom (using find as vlookup)